# Automatic cell width on table-layout fixed, but the last cell

Tags: css, breadcrumbs, tablecell

I want to create a breadcrumb for a website.

The elements should expand to fill all of the available space. If they couldn't fit on it, I'd like to have their inner text clipped with `text-overflow: ellipsis`, except the last one.

In other words: have the last element with the full width, and distribute the other ones on the remaining space (with width depending on their content, or if not possible at least they should't look bad...).

I tried with this code.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>paka</li>
        <li>ultrapaka</li>
        <li>ultrapaka</li>
        <li>ultrapaka ultrapaka</li>
        <li>daslidjsajdsa</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here the CSS:

```
div {
    display: table;
    margin: 5px;
    border:1px solid #777;
    padding: 3px;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

ul {
    display: table-row;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

If I put `table-layout: fixed` the table really constrains its space, but I lose the automatic cell width.

If I don't put it, the table just overflows outside of its limits.

You can find a JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SaFmL/). (I have set the table width to 400px to show the desired effect, even though on the final solution it should expand at 100%).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do that is using flexbox properties, but it's hard to make it work for all browsers.

You could maybe give a fixed width or percentage for all cells, and use the `:last-child` selector to apply an auto width on the last cell.

You could also try `box-sizing`, but I'm not sure about the result.

Comment: I think the flexbox would be the right way to go (can you make a real world example of it?). I'm not so sure about the other two solutions you said. Anyway, I solved the problem with some sort of an hack (media queries FTW).

Comment: Here is a good tutorial from Smashing Mag : http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/
Take care, there is a lot of differents properties, a lot of changes have been made in the last 3 years !